Showing azimuth/heading of points as arrows
I am trying to display a set of points as arrows that point towards the direction given by a known angle (in my case, the angle is the geometric heading, i.e. counterclockwise from East, in radians).
My layer has longitude, latitude and heading attributes, so to display the points as arrows, I go to Symbology and use the Vector Field Marker as follows:

However, the arrows are displayed with a wrong angle like so:

As you can see the arrows are not pointing in the "direction of movement", and I confirmed the displayed angle was indeed wrong by roughly measuring the X/Y components of the arrows in pixels, which gave me an angle of 60° while the true heading angle here is 83° for the arrow highlighted in red.
So far, I have tried changing the rendering CRS to epsg:4326 or epsg:3857, and even using the Globe View plugin to get a round Earth, but couldn't get the arrows pointing correctly. I also tried computing the azimuths from point to point with Python like so:
features[i].geometry().asPoint().azimuth(features[i+1].geometry().asPoint())

but the angle is off, because the azimuth computation is just arctan2(longitude2 - longitude1, latitude2 - latitude1) which is incorrect (it assumes a flat Earth). And I already computed the value that I want to display anyway...
EDIT: here is some example CSV data:
longitude,latitude,heading,speed
1.359324901064686,43.620965102044295,1.474579266257513,20
1.359325604772741,43.620971263011889,1.507498777058166,20
1.359326087431660,43.620977485153766,1.451068567678169,20
1.359327163777192,43.620983451836146,1.401384010237002,20

Could you share some example data?

@Erik Sure, I added some points in my question

Wonderful, thank you.

I suggest you switch from counterclockwise from east to clockwise. For the example data this looks fine.

Okay, after trying what Erik suggested, the issue is indeed related to the Counterclockwise from East setting in the Vector Field Marker.
I get the desired results if I compute azimuth = pi()/2 - heading and set it as the Angle attribute of the vector field, and set Angle orientation to Clockwise from north
